# Reading file line by line from #1comment till #2nd comment

Tags: python-3.x, file, readlines

i want to read, parse a .txt file and save it in a variables. After first comment #a till end of #~~ to variable a then for var b: to read after comment #b till comment #~~ and so on.

```
#a
  60   8   10
  12  30   12
#~~
#b  
14 2
30 12
#~~
#c
 40 14
```

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
         li = line.strip()
         if li.startswith("#a"):
```

Comment: You can just read in the entire file and process it afterward?

Comment: yes, would go as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might just read the entire file into Python, and then use `re.findall` to find all comments:

```py
inp = """#a
  60   8   10
  12  30   12
#~~
#b  
14 2
30 12
#~~
#c
 40 14
#~~"""

matches = re.findall('#(\\w+)\s+(.*?)#~~\s*', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
[('a', '60   8   10\n  12  30   12\n'), ('b', '14 2\n30 12\n'), ('c', '40 14\n')]
```

In place of the hard-coded data I have above, use the following to read from your actual file:

```py
file = open("file.txt")
inp = file.read()
file.close()
```

**Edit:**

If you only want to retain the comment data itself, but not the labels, then reduce the 2D list to a 1D list via a comprehension:

```py
matches = re.findall('#(\\w+)\s+(.*?)#~~\s*', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
output = [j for (i, j) in matches]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['60   8   10\n  12  30   12\n', '14 2\n30 12\n', '40 14\n']
```

Comment: ok, this would be a method. Could you comment your findall expression.  for example if I wanna exclude the letter a  as well

Comment: @pythonabsir You could use a negative lookahead to exclude the key `a`, e.g. use `#((?!a\s+)\\w+)\s+(.*?)#~~\s*` ... [see the demo](https://rextester.com/QAVKH11091).

Comment: though mean, just exclude always the whole first comment, second comment, etc., so to include only the numbers

Comment: @pythonabsir Check the updated answer if you want to retain only the comments but not the labels.